# Problem with the persistence of a live CD?

Tags: 12.04, boot, persistence

I am NOT using an USB here, but I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS onto a CD and am trying to create a persistent bootable CD.

My Boot Menu

[image]

As you can see, I have tried to add "persistent" at the end of the boot options. But it has not helped to actually create the persistence I am looking for.

If anyone could help, that would be great! Thanks :)
Or even answer if this is possible?

Comment: You write "But it has not helped to actually create the persistence I am looking for." Can you describe exactly what you mean by persistence? I suspect you mean something different than Ubuntu means. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to have a live cd with persistence, a persistence file is only possible on a usb thumbdrive or external hdd. For more information:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence